# Disable Button After Click for Each User

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am working on a budgeting app using PHP HTML and a touch of JS.

I want to have an import button that can only be clicked one time by the user then it is disabled or hidden even if they refresh the page, But for a new user, it would still be available until they click it.

I have tried code like this but it is available to click again after each refresh.

```
<form action='/' method='POST' onsubmit='disableButton()'>
    <input name='txt' type='text' required />
    <button id='btn' type='submit'>Post</button>
</form>

<script>
    function disableButton() {
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn.innerText = 'Posting...'
    }
</script>
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You are going to need to use a Backend Database, `localStorage` or `cookies`

Comment: Do you want to know if it's disable by an account user or by him web interface ?

Comment: if it's by an account user you need a database, if it's not you will use localstore. You should use a database for that because if he use firefox and disable it, on chrome that will not disable it. and if he clean is web storage and cookie he will enable it again.

Comment: I would prefer is to use my Database user to accomplish this. I have a mysql database that stores usernames, session_id, passwords, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, as some others have said, you are going to need an backend database, but, we can also implement this using localstorage and cookies. Here is how you could do it:

```
<form action='/' method='POST' onsubmit='refresh()'>
    <input name='txt' type='text' required />
    <button id="refresh" type='submit'>Post</button>
</form>
<script>
  const refreshBtn = document.getElementById("refresh");
  refreshBtn.addEventListener("click", refresh);
  disable();

  function disable() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("disableButton?")) {
      refreshBtn.setAttribute("disabled", ""); 
    }
  }
  
  function refresh() {
    localStorage.setItem("disableButton?", "yes");
  };
</script>
```

Code explanation:
When you submit the form, it saves in local storage that the button is clicked. Then when the user comes back, it runs `disable()` which checks if the local storage value exists, and if it does, it disables the submit button.

If this doesn’t work please tell me.

(Also, if the user clears his history and cookies, then the user will be able to submit the form, so it’s better to use an database for this then doing this.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do have a backend database using MySQL. I use PHP to access it via mysqli and I have a login system with users. Currently I utilize session_id and username to identify them in other areas of my code. I just don't know how to use JS and PHP together to accomplish what I am trying to do here. Ill definitely give this a shot though!